# Showing screen splash with Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Does anyone know how to show a screen splash in Google App Script?. I want to show a screen splash while I check the rows of a spreadsheet. Thank you.

Comment: HAve you looked at [HTML Service: Create and Serve HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/) and specifically the heading [Serve HTML as a Google Docs, Sheets, or Forms user interface](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/#serve_html_as_a_google_docs_sheets_or_forms_user_interface)

Comment: Thank @Karl_S, I'll try to use this way but I am not sure about it will be valid.

Comment: Hi @Karl_S, I've revised the docummentatio but it is no possible to do what I want to do. Anyway, thanks a lot for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the Splash Screen as an HTML file in the script editor.  Under File->New select Html file.  Call the file test_HTML and place this inside the file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    Splash
  </body>
  <script>

  setTimeout(myFunction, 3000)

  function myFunction() {
    google.script.host.close();
  }
  </script>
</html>
```

In Code.gs place the following:

```
function onEdit(e){

  var splashScreen = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('test_HTML')
        .setHeight(600)
        .setWidth(600);

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .showModalDialog(splashScreen, 'Dialog title');

}
```

In this case on and Edit of the document, the Splash Screen HTML will pop up and display for 3 seconds.  You will have to modify this to work with your code, but should give you the basic principal of using the HTML Service as a splash screen.